# 'c' - 'Ç' like case in-sensitive query in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an autocompleter box to search a model. And in search method i have a condition like

```
MyModel.where("upper(translate(content,'ıişğüçö\302\240','IİŞĞÜÇÖ')) like '%#{q}%'")
```

If query str : "çağdaş", query will find "Çağdaş" or "çaĞdaş" etc.

But now i want to extend this search method. I want my query to find "Çagdaş" with "cagdas" and for ex.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this;

First i converted characters in query string which is not in English. Like `ç => c, İ => I`

then i re-write my condition string like ;

```
MyModel.where("translate(content,'ışğüçöİŞĞÜÇÖ','isgucoISGUCO') ilike '%#{q}%'")
```

Now it works like what it needs to.

Note that it is very specific solution.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your database...
In postgres you can use the ILIKE SQL function

Which DBMS and charset are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Although I'm personally not that happy with using DB specific SQL, I'd suggest to have a look at the fuzzymatch operations in PostgresQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

[edit]: [Here](http://railsmonkey.net/2010/05/did-you-mean-style-searching-in-your-database/)'s a more generic approach that needs or relies on precalculation of the matching algorithm (soundex is an old one but you may find a lot in Google about this)

Comment: `Note that Soundex is not very useful for non-English names.`. My db is not also non-english.